# How to debug a process launched from a debugged process

Tags: visual-studio

I'm developing a launcher application (WinForms, C#). This means that I have three project, let's call them A, B, and Launcher; Launcher has two buttons to start A and B respectively. It does so via Process.Start, effectively launching the exe's as a new process.

My problem is that when I run Launcher in the debugger, if I click A, a new process of A is launched, but it is not attached to the debugger.

I know I can attach it at any time, but what I ask is: **is there a way to "auto-attach" the process that is launched from a process that is being debugged?**

Comment: With WinDbg, it's easy: just run `.childdbg 1` after attaching to the parent. Or, you can configure the global flags to accomplish the same goal. I'm not sure if there's something similar in Visual Studio. I haven't seen it. You might need to write an add-in. Or try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I tried several times, but if I follow the guide you linked I don't get to have the process attached to a new VS debugger - nor the the existing one.